# How to refactor class hierarchies to avoid diamond problem?

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor, diamond-problem

Suppose I have a large class hierarchy as a single rooted tree, with root being `class A` such that each of its offsprings has its own implementation of `void f(...)` and `void g(...)`, with different argument lists.

I have another class `class X: public A` that only uses the base class `f(...)` and `g(...)` in some of its methods. Now I want to extend methods in `X` to all subtype of `A`: say the subtype of `A` be `B`, the new class is `class BX`. The requirement is:

1. (implementation) `class BX` should use `f(...)` and `g(...)` from `class B`, and all methods from `class X`.
2. (interface) `class BX` should adhere to the interface of `class A`.

The solution I came up with is to have `template<typename B> class BX: public B` to avoid the diamond problem in 1.

Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I am unclear what you mean by "different argument lists"; you mean they both overload and override f and g?

Comment: yeah they both overload and overrides f() and g().

Comment: Please show some [mcve].

Comment: Overloads are hardly relevant. Functions with same names and different arguments are just unrelated functions.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience quite a few problems with inheritance go away if you only inherit interfaces (i.e virtual only) and use composition and delegation to share implementations, however the curiously recurring template pattern or CRTP, which is what you've used here is another common way of working around this problem.

Comment: Hi can you explain why this is CRTP? I am forming only one more subtype `BX` for each subtype `B` of `A` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class D>
struct X {
  A* self(){ return static_cast<D*>(this); }
  A const* self() const{ return static_cast<D*>(this); }
  void foo(){
    self()->f( 1, 2, 3 );
  }
};

struct XA: A, X<XA> {};
struct XB: B, X<XB> {};
```

Within `X<XB>`, the implementation of `XB`, you only have access to `A`.

If you want users to only see `A` only expose `XB`s as an `A`.

Note this might be quite useless, as accessing any changes in `XB`/`X<XB>` requires knowing your object isn't an `A`, as `X<XB>` doesn't modify anything in `A`'s interface.

Comment: Can you explain why do I need one more level of indirection with `struct X`? Is it to cast `XB` as `A`? Also if `A::f(int, int)` and `B::f(double, double)`, should I add two function `void A::foo() {dof();}; virtual void A::dof() {};` to `class A` and implement `dof()` for each subtype `B` of `A`?

Comment: @user You seemed to want to restrict the implementation of `X` to only using `A` interface.  I tried to do that.

Comment: I see. I am reading C++PL section 27.4.1 and I can see what you are doing here now.